# react Native request failed with 415

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am using react native and I want to send some document file to server using patch request.

This is the form data which I am sending

[image]

Below is the fetch code

```
export const stepStageFour = (data,id) => {
    console.log("Statge Four")
    console.log(data)
    return dispatch => {
    return client().patch('internal/activation/step-4/'+id+'/',{
        headers: {
            'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
            "Authorization" : 'JWT Any Token ID',
        },data
    }).catch( data => console.log(data))

    }
}
```

but when I am making request I am getting the below error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> 415 means that the media type is unsupported.
>   You're sending the JSON so just put the content-type in your header.

Add this to your request header

`'Content-Type': 'application/json',`

Comment: Thanks @Siraj

But still getting the same error

I have updated the form data to JSON.stringify(formData)

Comment: so code look like the below 

```const fdata = JSON.stringify(data)
    return dispatch => {
    return client().patch('internal/activation/step-4/'+id+'/',{
        headers: {
            'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
            "Authorization" : 'JWT any token id',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },fdata
    }).catch( data => console.log(data))
    
    }```

Comment: do I have to do the below first.
````
const fdata = JSON.stringify(data) 
````
and then pass fdata to request ??

Comment: You don't need to stringify the data. It should work fine simply with json and adding content type as application/json.

Comment: Also add `"Accept": "application/json"` on the header without stringify it.

Comment: I am sorry but I did the same and getting the same result I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: my code looks like this now 

````export const stepStageFour = (data,id) => {
    console.log("Statge Four")
    console.log(data)
return dispatch => {
    return client().patch('internal/activation/step-4/'+id+'/',{
        headers: {
            'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
            "Authorization" : 'JWT any token',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },data
    }).catch( data => console.log(data))
    
    }
  ````

Comment: the data I am sending is in the below format

````FormData {_parts: Array(3)}
_parts: Array(3)
0: Array(2)
0: "registration_file"
1:
name: "ticket.pdf"
type: "file"
uri: "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540jasham%252Feugene-admin-app/DocumentPicker/2c178abc-167e-4c72-981c-522410ecb823pdf"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
1: (2) ["company_pan_file", {…}]````

Comment: This is the format of data
````formData = new FormData()

               formData.append('registration_file',{ type: "file" ,uri : this.state.ifcs_file.uri, name : this.state.ifcs_file.name, })
               formData.append('company_pan_file',{ type: "file" , uri : this.state.company_pan.uri, name : this.state.company_pan.name,})
               formData.append('address_proof', { type: "file" , uri : this.state.adder_proof.uri, name : this.state.company_pan.name, })````